# Youtube iframe failed to load in Android

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to play YouTube Videos on android devices using webview and youtube iframe api. While testing the same on 4.2 devices, it did work on 4.2.2 Nexus 4. But when I tried it on Sony Xpedia L, its showing the buffering status, but the video never gets loaded (Screen Shots attached). What could be a fix for this? Any suggestions...?!?!

[image: When Clicking on Play Button]

[image: When trying to seek/jump to a point using Javascript]

My code is as follows..

JAVA CODE

```
wvVideo = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvVideo);
wvVideo.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
WebSettings webSettings = wvVideo.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
wvVideo.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
wvVideo.loadUrl("http://test.com/iframeYouTube.html?videoid="+videoURL); 
wvVideo.loadUrl("javascript:playVideo();");
```

XML

```
<WebView
android:id="@+id/wvVideo"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:background="#212121"></WebView>
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;width:100%">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
  <body style="background:#212121;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0">

<!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
<div id="player" style="margin:0;padding:0"></div>

<script>

    var Query = function () {

    var query_string = {};
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");

    if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
      query_string[pair[0]] = pair[1];

    } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
      var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]], pair[1] ];
      query_string[pair[0]] = arr;

    } else {
      query_string[pair[0]].push(pair[1]);
    }
    } 

    return query_string;
    } ();

    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height:'100%',width:'100%',

    videoId: Query.videoid,
    playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0, 'controls': 0, 'showinfo':0, 'modestbranding':1},
    events: {

    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange

    }
    });


  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
  cueCheck();
  timerFunction();
  videoLength();
  }

  var done = false;

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    Android.playState(event.data+"");

    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      done = true;
    }
  }

  function cueCheck()
  {
    Android.playState("cued");
  }

  function timerFunction(){
  console.log("function");
  Android.updateTimer(player.getCurrentTime()+"");
  setTimeout(timerFunction, 20);
 }

 function videoLength(){
  Android.getVideoLength(player.getDuration()+"");
 }

  function seekTo(val) {
  player.seekTo(val);
  // player.playVideo();
  }

  function pauseVideo(){
  player.pauseVideo()
  }

  function playVideo(){
  player.playVideo()
  }



    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The same video url when opened in Google Chrome in the same phone works fine! Its within the app that it has an issue..

Answer (score 0):

```
String html = getHTML(url);
MainActivity.webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
MainActivity.webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
final String mimeType = "text/html";
final String encoding = "UTF-8";
MainActivity.webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
MainActivity.webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, mimeType,
                encoding, "");

public static String getHTML(String str) {

    String html = "<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" style=\"overflow:hidden; width: 100%; height: 95%; scrolling=\"no\" padding:0px; margin:0px\" id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/"
            + str
            + "?html5=1&autoplay=1 & fs=0\" frameborder=\"0\" >\n"
            + "</iframe>\n ";

    return html;
}
```

Comment: Tried this.. Issue persisting :(

Comment: sorry bro but its working for me for my all devices but i dont have sony mobile :(

Comment: Had you also faced the same issue?!

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue and the only thing that i can say is that the error is related with the Android version. Particularly, as I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31591010/youtube-iframe-player-wont-show-videos-in-android-4-x-webview/38410424#38410424) :

- In Android 4 versions, can't autoplay. The user has to press play button into the iframe to start play the video. Particularly:

  - In Android 4.1 it reproduces the audio but not the image.
  - In Android 4.3 i tested in devices which can reproduce audio but no
    video and devices that can't reproduce anything.
  - In Android 4.4 don't reproduce anything
- From Android 5 and + everything works fine.

I spend so many time trying to do it i don't find the way :(