# Youtube iframe player won't show videos in android 4.x WebView

Tags: android, webview, youtube, chromium, youtube-javascript-api

I'm trying to use the youtube iframe player inside an android WebView but it fails on android 4.x while on 5.x everything works great.
When I try it in 4.x the player loads the video, when I start it I see nothing but hear the video sound.
The logcat gets filled with chromium error messages over and over again:

```
E/chromium(20362): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(5942)] [.Compositor-Onscreen-0x5db83bb8]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glUseProgram: program not linked
E/chromium(20362): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(5718)] [.Compositor-Onscreen-0x5db83bb8]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glUniformMatrix4fv: wrong uniform function for type
E/chromium(20362): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(5718)] [.Compositor-Onscreen-0x5db83bb8]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glUniform1iv: wrong uniform function for type
```

Here's how I set the WebView:

```
this.webview = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webview);

WebSettings settings = this.webview.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);

this.webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
...
this.webview.loadUrl(ADDRESS_OF_PAGE);
```

Also, I enable hardware acceleration in the manifest:

```
<application
    ...
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
```

Here's the js part:

```
var player;
var VIDEO_ID = "EIsauUFIguE";

window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    console.log("youtube api ready, loading player");

    player = new YT.Player("playerIframe", {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        videoId: null,
        events: {
            onReady: onPlayerReady,
            onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange,
            onPlaybackQualityChange: onPlayerPlaybackQualityChange,
            onError: onPlayerError
        },
        playerVars: {
            modestbranding: 1,
            playsinline: 1,
            fs: 0,
            showinfo: 0
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    console.log("player is ready: ", event);
    playVideo();
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    console.log("player state change: ", event);
}

function onPlayerPlaybackQualityChange(event) {
    console.log("player playback quality change: ", event);
}

function onPlayerError(event) {
    console.log("player error: ", event);
}

function playVideo() {
    console.log("playing video: " + VIDEO_ID);
    player.loadVideoById(VIDEO_ID);
    player.setPlaybackQuality("medium");
}

function loadPlayer() {
    console.log("loading youtube api");

    var tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
}

loadPlayer();
```

Any idea why it behaves this way and only in android 4.x?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but after fighting with this long time, i didn't find a solution. I tested all the configurations with webview and did many different html changes to put the iframe.

After my researching i only can add:

- In Android 4 versions, can't autoplay. The user has to press play button into the iframe to start play the video. Particularly:

  - In Android 4.1 it reproduces the audio but not the image.
  - In Android 4.3 i tested in devices which can reproduce audio but no video and devices that can't reproduce anything.
  - In Android 4.4 don't reproduce anything
- From Android 5 and + everything works fine.

Good luck and I plus vote this question to know if anyone can put light into this question :)